# How to use make multiple plots with ggplot using the same function?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to use `ggplot` to plot a series of graphs and then stack them using `grid.arrange`. The problem is that `ggplot` doesn't "use" the data supplied until `grid.arrange` is called, which forces me to store the data in `.GlobalEnv`, and I can't figure out how to avoid conflicting names. To illustrate with an MWE:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

plot.one.graph <- function(data)
{
    p <- ggplot(data, aes(x = category, y = value))
    p <- p + geom_bar(alpha = 0.5, stat = "identity")

    se.minus <- data$value - 1  # fake error bar
    se.plus <- data$value + 1
    assign("se.minus", se.minus, globalenv())
    assign("se.plus", se.plus, globalenv())
    p <- p + geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = se.minus, ymax = se.plus))

    return(p)
}

data.list <- list(  data.frame(category = 1:10, value = rnorm(10, 5)),
                    data.frame(category = 1:10, value = rpois(10, 5)))

ps <- list()
for (i in 1:len(data.list)) {
    ps[[i]] <- plot.one.graph(data.list[[i]])
}
grid.arrange(ps[[1]], ps[[2]])
```

Here I have two `data.frame`'s and I want to plot them one on top of another. The output looks like this [image: output]. Because the latter loop overwrites the (fake) error bar data for the first loop, the error bars were correct for the second graph but wrong for the first. I have tried various ways of storing the variable in `.GlobalEnv` but nothing seems to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Side notes: `1:len(data.list)` should probably be `1:length(data.list)` or even `seq_along(data.list)` and `ps <- list()` would be better as `ps <- vector("list", length(data.list))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return a built grob from the plot function, thus avoiding the need for `.GlobalEnv`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

plot.one.graph <- function(data) {

    p <- ggplot(data, aes(x = category, y = value))
    p <- p + geom_bar(alpha = 0.5, stat = "identity")

    data$ymin <- data$value - 1
    data$ymax <- data$value + 1

    p <- p + geom_errorbar(data=data, 
                           aes(ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax))

    p <- p + ylim(0,11)

    return(ggplotGrob(p))

}

set.seed(1492)
data.list <- list(data.frame(category = 1:10, value = rnorm(10, 5)),
                  data.frame(category = 1:10, value = rpois(10, 5)))

ps <- lapply(data.list, plot.one.graph)

do.call(grid.arrange, c(ps, ncol=2))
```

[image]

I added a `set.seed` so you'll get the same results on your system. Also, I changed the loop for how the plots are generated and used `do.call` to do the final render. I only did a horizontal layout and added a `ylim` so it was easier to see that the error bars were, in fact, different.